# Include different elements on JMenu and equal elements on all JMenuItem

Tags: java, jmenu, jmenuitem

I'm trying to create a JMenu (State) with some elements (States) and put SubMenus (Cities) with JMenuItem (ProductCategory).

My problem is, how can I select some cities and put in specific State and how to get every productCategory and link with to all cities?

At the present moment only [0] the first State is opening the and the [0] city is opening the category.

[JFrame Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn8zR.png)

Comment: One top JMenu. Per state a JMenu to be added in the top menu, containing the cities. Per city a JMenuItem. You need not create fields for all menues, just a new JMenu for every state.

Comment: Generally, this type of selection is done with JComboBoxes.

Comment: I'll check the JComboBoxex, but with JMenu the appearance would be better.

Thanks.